# Chat laravel 5 and notificaciones whit Whatsapp

Tags: laravel, notifications, chat, alert, whatsapi

I'm doing a system with laravel 5 and want have a method of notification alerts to phone mobile. I have read that I can do it with whatsapi but not as useful or good that is.

Any advice or recommendation?

Comment: Do you want push notifications send from Laravel?

Comment: If, suppose the system alerted that something was defeated, the user should receive a message with this alert

Answer (score 2):

You could do through push notifications, I would recommend you use this library https://packagist.org/packages/davibennun/laravel-push-notification to integrate to Laravel. You can send with push notification a payload with data for your app use it.